# Which group watches over Anti-Heroes according to the 'Treaty of Tolerance'?

Tags: venture-bros

In the most recent season of Venture Brothers, we've learned more about how the OSI and GCI handle 'protagonist' and 'antagonist' relations respectively.  They say a 'mad scientist' falls under the GCI's control, even though the scientist was at one time a normal scientist.

Where do Anti-Heroes, like the Blue Morpho, fall under?